# Visual Studio debugger randomly skipping over lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

```
        string generatedCode = "";
        generatedCode += "            ";
        int enumFieldsLength = 12; // Set equal to number of spaces in current indentation

        for(int i = 0; i < dbTableList.Count; i++)
        { // enum
            generatedCode += dbTableList[i].DbField;
            if(i != dbTableList.Count - 1)
            {
                generatedCode += ",";

                enumFieldsLength += dbTableList[i].DbField.Length + 2; // 2 for the comma + space
                if(enumFieldsLength <= SourceCode.MAX_CHARACTERS_PER_LINE)
                {
                    generatedCode += " "; // Add space after trailing comma
                }
                else
                {
                    enumFieldsLength = 12;
                    generatedCode += "\r\n            "; // New line because exceeded maximum allowed characters per line
                }
            }
        }
```

I have this simple code here. Running Visual Studio 2019. Visual Studio is behaving strangely.
Inside the else condition, the "enumFieldsLength = 12" is completely skipped by the debugger. Even if I move it after the string concatenation statement, it completely skips it.
Furthermore, the current line in debugger marker becomes a strange block.

On a likely related note, the correlating if statement will not let me select the code line (it just selects the closing bracket below it). And selecting the opening bracket shows up weird.
[image]

A similar thing is true inside the else. the enumFieldsLength = 12 selection shows up weird (selects some space before the code), but it will not let me select generatedCode += ..., it just kicks me down to the closing bracket.
[image]

When I am actually debugging, the current line indicator gets all weird near those lines.[image]

Furthermore, even when I am still inside the for loop, the debugger will mark pieces outside the loop. Look at this image, where the debugger has highlighted part of a statement outside the loop in a way that makes no sense.
[image]

What is going on, and how do I fix this? I have ReSharper, but I tried disabling it and it didn't help.
I also tried cleaning the solution and cleaning each individual project, rebuilding. The "Optimize code" is unchecked.

Comment: seems like your debugging-information is out of date. Just rebuild your solution.

Comment: @HimBromBeere As I said, I tried cleaning the solution and the individual project. Which means it's been rebuilt afterwards.

Comment: Especially the selection of whitespace would definitely indicate outdated debugging symbols, instead of an optimized build where it is determined that all assigments to `enumFieldsLength` are unused and therefore removed. Have you tried closing Visual Studio and deleting the bin and obj folders manually? Cleaning sometimes silently fails.

Comment: I just tried that and it worked. That's so stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

I manually deleted the bin and obj folders, then rebuilt each individual project manually.

On another note, Visual Studio seems to do weird things when doing git operations externally, like randomly removing lines in the csproj files and .sln file. In my most recent git merge, it looks like it had removed a random line from the .sln.
[image]

I'm not 100% sure this line caused it to start acting up (since other things I did after that merge worked fine, plus deleting the bin folders solved it without me messing with the sln), but regardless I reverted that change as well. The person I merged with didn't add or remove any files, so the sln shouldn't have changed (and din't on their branch, it's just Visual Studio being weird).

Comment: The debugger is mainly led by the symbol files, so if weird things happen like this, deleting the previous binaries and symbol files should be the first thing to try (as you did).

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2022 > Project Properties > Application > General > Target Framework, Toggle the .NET Framework Target up or down :-)